# how to install all smartphone drivers on windows computer to use with adb

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, smartphone

how to install all smartphone drivers on my computer to use with adb and share file and avoid install every cellphone driver one by one, I have seen computers in my college that have all smartphone drivers installed and recognize all smartphone when you plug it in through usb

Comment: How do you know these computers have drivers for ALL smartphones?

Comment: bacause nobody has complain about it and its a it carreer and belive me almost eveyone connect their smartphone to the computers in class

Comment: Then what are you trying to accomplish? Is the issue that YOUR phone isn't recognized by the computers? Your question lacks the information necessary for us to understand what you're actually asking. Use the EDIT button to add this required information.

Comment: im asking for a universal driver for all smartphones

Comment: There isn't one. While the answer celow will cover many phones, it will not support all services on those phones and many phones will not be supported at all. There must be a reason you want universal drivers, the REASON why you think these drivers are your solution will help us get you information more specific to your needs. There are lots of reasons to want phone drivers, and not all of these reasons have the same answer. Your continued resistance to giving this information means we are not able give you the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason why "computers in your college that have all smartphone drivers installed" is because at some point different individuals with different smartphones plugged in their smartphones and the drivers were thus installed at different times not necessarily there was an "all in one driver package" that was installed.

> For Windows, one usually needs a device-specific driver to get ADB
>   working. If you cannot find one for your device, you might want to
>   check with the [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/).

`adb` is also included in the Android SDK Platform-Tools package. You can download this package [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip). You can get more info on the [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

While the universal driver will most likely work with a lot of devices, you are not guaranteed it will be your 'all in one solution' because some brands require extra workarounds to be fully compatible with adb e.g Huawei, Xiaomi etc.

Acknowledgements

1. [Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)
2. [Android Enthusiasts Stack exchange: ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)